# Teradata - query invalid when importing file

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to import a csv in Teradata but I just get the message "query invalid" with no explanation. I tried changing the slashes to forward without any difference

```
create volatile table temp (
 a varchar(255)
);


.IMPORT vartext ',' FILE = 'F:\xyz\abcdef.csv', skip = 1;

delete from temp;
.QUIET ON
.REPEAT *
USING (
    a varchar(255)

)
INSERT INTO temp(a)
    VALUES (
        :a

    );
.QUIT
.LOGOFF
```

Comment: Do you run it in BTEQ?

Comment: Not directly relevant, but you will probably want to add `on commit preserve rows` to your volatile table declaration.

Comment: at which command does it break?